# Changes to MainStoryboard.storyboard no longer appear in my published app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I've been working away at a project of mine, when a couple days ago I noticed that changes I was making to the MainStoryboard.storyboard weren't occurring in the published version of my app. I tried adding new components and switching many elements and still no changes. I've tried cleaning and building, but the storyboard will still not update itself to my new changes. Changes I make to the code, however, work. I can dynamically populate a text field for example.

I feel like I've done something silly and not realized it, like somehow disconnected or duplicated the storyboard (though I only see one storyboard file in my list). I'm hoping someone has some ideas so I can progress with my project. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and it was due to localization which splits the storyboard into different ones for each language. It remains one file but xcode shows each localization in the address bar (or whatever it is called) if you select the storyboard in the file navigator.

Most likely you made changes for a storyboard language you don't use yourself for testing.